# Doing some things when my jQuery dialog is hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a jquery dialog on my page. When I don't need my dialog anymore, I "hide" it like this:

```
$('#modal-dialog').modal('hide');
```

My question: how can I bind an event on the 'hiding' (not really closing...) of the dialog to do some things.

I already this:

```
$('#modal-dialog').bind('dialogclose', function (event) {
    // do something here
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any built-in modal functions. Are you using the jQuery UI dialog and if so, shouldn't `$('#modal-dialog').modal('hide');` be `$('#modal-dialog').dialog('hide');`? Also bind has been deprecated in favor of on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the bootstrap modal library:

```
$('#modal-dialog').on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your modal is being hidden (and what event/s you want) you could just string what you want after the hide. If your hide is instant then you could just add more methods:
`$('#modal-dialog').modal('hide').append("<p>append some text</p>");` Otherwise I would recommend just making a little modal plugin to call the window, and then use `$("#modal-container").hide(function(){ //events events events });`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#dialog-modal").on('dialogclose', function (event, ui) {
        changeImage()
    })
```